# Connecting To A Website To Look Up A Word(Compiling Mass Data/Webcrawler)

Tags: c#, web-crawler

I am currently developing a Word-Completion application in C# and after getting the UI up and running, keyboard hooks set, and other things of that nature, I came to the realization that I need a WordList. The only issue is, I cant seem to find one with the appropriate information. I also don't want to spend an entire week formatting and gathering a WordList by hand.
The information I want is something like "TheWord, The definition, verb/etc."

So, it hit me. Why not download a basic word list with nothing but words(Already did this; there are about 109,523 words), write a program that iterates through every word, connects to the internet, retrieves the data(definition etc) from some arbitrary site, and creates XML data from said information. It could be 100% automated, and I would only have to wait for maybe an hour depending on my internet connection speed.

This however, brought me to a few questions.

1. How *should* I connect to a site to look up these words? **<< This my actual question.**
2. How would I read this information from the website?
3. Would I piss off my ISP or the website for that matter?
4. Is this a really bad idea? Lol.

How do you guys think I should go about this?

EDIT

Someone noticed that Dictionary.com uses the word as a suffix in the url. This will make it easy to iterate through the word file. I also see that the webpage is stored in XHTML(Or maybe just HTML). Here is the source for the Word "Cat". http://pastebin.com/hjZj6AC1

Comment: Do you have a site in mind?

Comment: @Vajura Dictionary.com?

Comment: What do you mean by how? As in what kind of library or class to use?

Comment: @muddymess What code would I use, how would YOU program something like this?

Comment: @Krythic since dictionary.com uses the word as the address you could simply pull all the html text from the site of lets say dog from http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/dog?s=t then parse through that to get al lthe data you need. Every word should have the same structure so you could do it like that

Comment: @Vajura I like that Idea. Now the question is, how to actually open said information. I see(via right click and view source) that the pages are stored in XHTML. What is the best way to open and parse that in C#?

Comment: It is something we do not tell you. Product recommendations are not on topic here. This is not a "do my work for me" service.

Comment: look at html agility pack (available on nuget)

Comment: in C# you can just use string html = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://twitter.com"); to get the site to a string then use regex to get the needed data. You will need to specify what you need if you want help with the regex

Comment: Regarding 3 and 4... Your ISP probably won't care. But the source that you're retrieving your definitions from might not appreciate it. Make sure that you're allowed to obtain their information and use it for your own purpose. Also make sure they appreciate you crawling their service, since it may impact the performance of their service.

Comment: Following on from @Onots, many sites that allow you to access their data have an API or machine readable format (wiktionary maybe?). Scraping from 3rd party sites without their permission is not only bad, but possibly illegal and against copyright.

Comment: @Deanna I was worried about something like that.

Comment: @Krythic just get something from Project Gutenberg maybe (e.g. http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/673). Your method is a little tedious anyway. Plus you will have to think through on how you will present each word. Very rarely will you get a word that only has one definition and is used only as a single part of speech (even Cat is both a verb and a noun, for example)

Comment: @Tyress I was honestly just thinking about abandoning the concept all together and offering a "Lookup Word" feature instaead, which just opens their web browser and automatically googles the word. Probably the easiest way to do it in the long run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what you marked as your actual question - you just need to download the data from the website and find what you need.
A great tool for this is [CsQuery](https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery) which allows you to use jquery selectors.
You could do something like this:

```
var dom = CQ.CreateFromUrl("http://www.jquery.com");
string definition = dom.Select(".definitionDiv").Text();
```